# How to connect an AWS RDS SQL instance to Databricks/Spark?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-rds

I'm trying to find a way to connect an AWS RDS instance to Spark in order to work on cloud only with no success. Is there a standard way to do that?

Thank you in advance

Comment: "with no success" - is not specific. What exactly did you do? What errors did you get? Do you have any code to share?

Comment: No, no code. I'm just looking for possible solutions around but I'm not figure out where to start.

Comment: just standard JDBC connector with JDBC driver specific for your implementation - postgres, etc: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html